# Magento Bestselling block shows disabled product

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

I cannot figure this out, i have magento 1.9 and a bestselling block with 6 items, one of these items is disabled, but still showing as bestselling, how do you remove this item from bestsellerslist?

Comment: How do you get bestseller products? Please paste the code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to exclude this problem product you will need to modify the code you are using to check to see if the products being displayed are available for sale.

If we look at the "Add to Cart" button as an example, the check is as follows:

```
if($_product->isSaleable())
```

or if there is more than 1 condition:

```
if($_product->isSaleable() &&
```

Without seeing your code it is difficult to give you a precise answer, but he above when implemented correctly will  help you achieve what you are looking for.

Good luck!